# How to break down a Django query-set in a template and then iterate?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-template-filters

lets say my view looks like this:

```
def index(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'myapp/index.html', {'posts' : posts})
```

I want to do something like this :

**index.html**

```
<div>
    {% for post in posts[:3] %}
        <p>{{post.text}}</p>
    {% endfor %}
</div>

<div>
    {% for post in posts[3:6] %}
        <p>{{post.text}}</p>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

In short, I want to break down my query-set into smaller groups of 3 and then iterate over them. Is there any easy way to do this?

Comment: I am not sure this type of slicing work in templates. You will need to use [`slice`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#slice) filter.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`forloop.counter`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#for) and [`divisibleby`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#divisibleby) to accomplish this:

```
<div>
    {% for post in posts %}
        <p>{{post.text}}</p>
        {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:3 %}
            </div><div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Alternatively, consider splitting the queryset into groups in the view and passing the groups to the template as a new context variable.